# Django - get() returned more than one it returned 700

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

I am having issues with a search form. I am trying to make a search field that queries the database and returns results on my results page. I have the page returning 1 result with a certain query and the other query with multiple rows I get this error **get() returned more than one MyModel -- it returned 791!**. This may seem silly as I am new to Django Forms. Please let me know if you need any other info. I have tried using .filter but that returns nothing. I have looked at multiple SO questions and some have helped but still having a little issue. My code is below:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Model


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        query = str(query)
        results = myModel.objects.get(
           site=query
        )
        context = {"results": results}
    return render(request, 'results.html', context)
```

results.html

```
{% if results %}
    <ul>
         <li><p>{{ results.url }}</p></li>
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>Nothing Available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

index.html

```
<form action="/results/" method="GET">
{% csrf_token %}
<input  id="search_box" type="text" name="q"  placeholder="Search...">
<button id="search_submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-defaultbtnlg"><i class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i> <span class="networkname">Search</span></button>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the point of your SQL query? You execute it, ignore the result, then do the same thing with Django model calls.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I meant to take that out let me edit it.

Comment: `get` expects to find only one result, if it finds more it throws an error, use `filter` for multiple results! (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#get)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your search query can return more than one result, so you should use `filter()` instead of `get()`.

```
results = myModel.objects.filter(
   site=query
)
```

Then in your template, loop through the results

```
{% if results %}
    <ul>
        {% for result in results %}
        <li><p>{{ result.url }}</p></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>Nothing Available.</p>
{% endif %}
```